# .htaccess Wildcard Redirect With GET Variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, get, wildcard, http-status-code-301

I am trying to redirect all of the following URLs on my site to a new version. Here is the goal:

BEFORE (Notice that there is no '.php')

```
https://example.com/view?username=asdf1234
```

REDIRECTS TO (With '.php' and inside the 'tool' folder)

```
https://example.com/tool/view.php?username=asdf1234
```

I've tried a couple examples but can't figure it out. This is my best guess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/view\?username=(.+) /tool/view.php?%1 [L,R=301]
```

---

Adding

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch ^/view(.*)$ https://example.com/tool/view.php$1
```

Successfully redirected but it is a 302 redirect. When I added [L,R=301] it gave a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a negative assertion:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" ^/tool/?.*$
RewriteRule ".?" "-" [S=1]
RewriteRule "^/(.*)$" "/tool/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}" [L,R=301]
```

- The first rule states a condition that the URL begins with /tool.
- The second rule states that if the first rule passes, **SKIP** the next 1
  rule.
- The third rule says to implement a redirect to `/tool/(TheUrlYouVisited.whatever)`

So, if the URL does not begin with /tool, the third rule will not be skipped, and thus you have your catch all redirect.

---

As a test, you could also just add a simple:

```
RedirectMatch ^/view(.*)$ http://www.example.com/tool/view$1
```

If that doesn't work, you know something else entirely is going on.

Comment: I just tried it and when I visit https://example.com/view?username=test nothing redirects

Comment: do you have other rewrite rules taking precedence? maybe higher up somewhere

Comment: I moved it to the top of my .htaccess file and nothing is redirecting.

Comment: Add a syntax error to .htaccess and see if the site loads. If it loads, you know the .htaccess file is not even being looked at.

Comment: I added your second code and the page successfully redirected. How would I make it a 301 redirect instead of a 302 redirect

Comment: Just put a 301 right after RedirectMatch, like this site has examples: https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4565193.htm